# No procedure with the name 'gds.beta.kmeans.stream'

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to neo4j and trying to run a k-means clustering algo. I recieve this error: "There is no procedure with the name `gds.beta.kmeans.stream` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed."

Looking around I see it has to do with the version of the GDS plugin. I have the most current version downloaded. I have been following this tutorial to attempt k-means clustering (https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/alpha/kmeans/).

How do determine the correct function name based on the version?

```
CALL gds.beta.kmeans.stream('bd', {
    nodeProperty: 'bd_load',
    k:3,
    randomSeed:42})
    YIELD nodeId, communityId
    RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, communityId
    ORDER BY communityId, name ASC
```

Comment: Can you run `RETURN gds.version()` to verify the version of the plugin?

Comment: gds version '2.1.8'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs say it is alpha tier at the moment. Try:

```
CALL gds.alpha.kmeans.stream('bd', {
    nodeProperty: 'bd_load',
    k:3,
    randomSeed:42})
    YIELD nodeId, communityId
    RETURN gds.util.asNode(nodeId).name AS name, communityId
    ORDER BY communityId, name ASC
```